# react native delete an item from an array list

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to delete an item from a list in react native but its not working

```
handleDeletePost = (passedItem) => {
  const { userPosts } = this.state;
  const newArray = userPosts.map(item => {
  if (item.headline === passedItem.headline) {

  Alert.alert(
    'Delete Post',
    'Are you sure to delete Post?',
    [
      {text: 'Yes', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
      {text: 'No', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'}
    ],
    { cancelable: false }
  )
  }
});
}
```

When i hit delete i get an error: can't find variable index

Comment: Beside the error you get, not sure that's a good way to use `map`. It would be nice to try first to find the element you want to remove and the you `Array.slice` it out after `onPress` confirmation.

Comment: check if userPosts array is filled also use this.state.userPosts.map

Answer (score 1):

Your map doesnt look like its being used corrently, but to remove  an item from an array use the .splice() function.

EXAMPLE

```
var array = [2, 5, 9];
console.log(array)
var index = array.indexOf(5);
if (index > -1) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

OUTPUTS

```
array[2, 9]
```

Hope this helps :)